# can python 3.2 http.client.HTTPConnection download big file?

Tags: python, download

Can http.client.HTTPConnection on python 3.2 download big file about 1G ?
I'm get source of class HTTPResponse
when i read content, all data will save to variable and return it,can variable save 1G data to memory ?

I want save data to order socket as tunnel,i don't see yield keyword any where on HTTPResponse ?

can http.client.HTTPConnection run this task ?
tks :D

Answer (score 2):

Read the response in chunks. It can download them.

```
import http.client
conn = http.client.HTTPConnection("www.python.org")
conn.request("GET", "/index.html")
r1 = conn.getresponse()
print(r1.status, r1.reason)

data1 = r1.read()  # This will return entire content.
# The following example demonstrates reading data in chunks.
conn.request("GET", "/index.html")
r1 = conn.getresponse()
while not r1.closed:
    print(r1.read(200)) # 200 bytes
```